# Return variable from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, return

This section of a program I am writing is supposed to take the random choice and then print it outside the function (I can't print from within as I need the variable later).
I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I am unsure what it is.

```
#python2
def CompTurn():
  RandTurn = [Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4]
  Choice = random.choice(RandTurn)
  return(Choice)
print Choice
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Choice` a *global* or *local* variable?...If it is only defined with the `CompTurn` function, then you cannot reference it outside this function.

Comment: >>>I can't print from within as I need the variable later - you can print the variable inside your function and return the variable(whatever value the variable holds) if you want the value outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
Choice = CompTurn()
```

before your print statement. Because the variables you declare within the function are not known outside of it, you have to store (or print directly, but then you cannot store it) the returned variable in a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your function correctly, but you never executed it! (You'll see that if you make it print something as a diagnostic.) You must run it to get the result:

```
chosen = CompTurn()
print chosen
```

Note that I used a different variable name. You *could* use the same variable name as a variable in your function, but it's still a different variable than the one in your function.

It is also important to realize that your function returns a *value,* not a variable. You can assign the value to a variable (as above) or print it immediately.

```
print CompTurn()
```

Answer (score 1):

About your program, you don't need the brackets for `return`. It's s statement, not a function.

```
def CompTurn():
  RandTurn = [Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4]
  Choice = random.choice(RandTurn)
  return Choice
```

Shorter:

```
def CompTurn():
      RandTurn = [Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4]
      return random.choice(RandTurn)
```

To print the return value, You can save it in a variable and print it

```
ret = CompTurn()
print ret
```

Or print directly:

```
print CompTurn()
```